# How do you setup heroku_san with Sinatra?

Tags: deployment, heroku, heroku-san

For example how do you push code to specific heroku application using the heroku_san rake shortcut commands, eg.

```
rake otherapp heroku:push
```

(taken from http://jqr.github.com/2010/08/27/easy-heroku-deploys-with-heroku-san.html )

I keep getting:

```
rake aborted!
Don't know how to build task 'otherapp'
```

I have a config directory under my sinatra app. And this contains a heroku.yml as mentioned in the above guide. The file looks like this

```
apps:
  production: mycoolherokuapp
  otherapp: myotherherokuapp
```

I have otherapp already created on heroku.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

heroku_san is Rails specific.

If you look at the lib code it uses: Rails.root.join, RAILS_ENV, Rails.configuration, and Railtie throughout.

Answer (score 0):

I'm working on a fork of heroku_san that will (eventually) remove the coupling between Rails & heroku_san. Right now, I'm working on making a testable class. https://github.com/kmayer/heroku_san  -- try it out and send me some feedback.

Answer (score 0):

Ken actually completed the Sinatra compatibility code and just released version 3.0.0 which includes Sinatra support.

Update your `Gemfile`:

```
group :development do
  gem 'heroku_san'
end
```

Update your `Rakefile`:

```
require "bundler/setup"
require "heroku_san"
config_file = File.join(File.expand_path(File.dirname(__FILE__)), 'config', 'heroku.yml')
HerokuSan.project = HerokuSan::Project.new(config_file, :deploy => HerokuSan::Deploy::Sinatra)
load "heroku_san/tasks.rb"
```

See documentation at https://github.com/fastestforward/heroku_san